# Weird identity for the divergence theorem / Divergence theorem for matrices

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, differential-forms

Our students were tasked, using the divergence theorem $ \int_V \nabla \cdot \vec{F} \mathrm{d}^3 r = \int_{\partial V} \vec{F} \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{a} $, to show that for any bounded, connected subset V of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with surface $\partial V$ the following identity holds:

$$\int_V \vec{r} \mathrm{d}^3r = \frac{1}{4} \int_{\partial V} \vec{r} \left( \vec{r} \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{a} \right)$$

where 
$$ \vec{r} = \begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now, the sample solution considered the i-th component of the right hand side (using Einstein sum convention):

$$ \left( \frac{1}{4} \int_{\partial V} \vec{r} \left( \vec{r} \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{a} \right) \right)_i = \frac{1}{4} \int_{\partial V} r_i r_j \mathrm{d}a_j = \frac{1}{4} \int_{\partial V} (r_i r_j) \mathrm{d}a_j \stackrel{Div. theorem}{=} \frac{1}{4} \int_V \partial_j (r_i r_j) \mathrm{d}^3r = \frac{1}{4} \int_V (\delta_{ij} r_j + 3r_i) \mathrm{d}^3r = \left(  \int_V \vec{r} \mathrm{d}^3r \right)_i  $$

On the other hand, many students used [a corollary of the divergence theorem for gradient fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1958252/gauss-divergence-theorem-for-volume-integral-of-a-gradient-field) $ \int_V \nabla \phi \mathrm{d}^3 r = \int_{\partial V} \phi\mathrm{d}\vec{a} $ by realizing that for $\phi = \frac{1}{2} \left( x_1^2 + x_2^2 +x_3^2 \right) = \frac{1}{2} r^2 = \frac{1}{2} \left( \vec{r} \cdot \vec{r} \right) $ we find

$$ \int_V \vec{r} \mathrm{d}^3 r = \int_V \nabla \phi \mathrm{d}^3 r =  \int_{\partial V} \phi\mathrm{d}\vec{a} = \frac{1}{2} \int_{\partial V} \left( \vec{r} \cdot \vec{r} \right) \mathrm{d}\vec{a} $$

Now, if both identities are correct, then $$\frac{1}{4} \int_{\partial V} \vec{r} \left( \vec{r} \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{a} \right) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{\partial V} \left( \vec{r} \cdot \vec{r} \right) \mathrm{d}\vec{a}$$

which looks temptingly similar. However, nobody was able to prove this relation and it is (to me) far from trivial to see why this relation should hold.

**Can anybody either show where a mistake is hidden or prove that the last identity is correct?**

I realize that the sample solution effectively applies the divergence theorem to the outer product of $\vec{r}$ with itself: $$\frac{1}{4} \int_{\partial V} \vec{r} \left( \vec{r} \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{a} \right) = \frac{1}{4} \int_{\partial V} \vec{r} \otimes \vec{r} \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{a} = \frac{1}{4} \int_{\partial V} \vec{r} 
\, \vec{r}^T \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{a} \stackrel{Div. theorem}{=} \frac{1}{4} \int_V  \nabla \cdot \left( \vec{r} 
\, \vec{r}^T \right) \mathrm{d}^3r $$

which I find very curious. I did not know you could apply the divergence theorem to matrix-like objects, however, for every example we constructed we always found that the identitiy of the problem was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice for any constant vector $\vec{k}$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\nabla \times ( r^2 (\vec{k} \times \vec{r}) )
&= \nabla r^2 \times (\vec{k} \times \vec{r} ) +
r^2 \nabla \times( \vec{k} \times \vec{r} )\\
&= 2 \vec{r} \times (\vec{k} \times \vec{r} )
+ r^2 ((\nabla \cdot \vec{r}) \vec{k} - \color{red}{(\vec{k} \cdot \nabla  )\vec{r}})\\
&= 2 (r^2 \vec{k} - (\vec{k}\cdot \vec{r})\vec{r}) + (3-\color{red}{1})r^2 \vec{k}\\
&= 4 r^2 \vec{k} - 2(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r})\vec{r}
\end{align}
$$
Divide by $8$, integrate over any surface $S$ and apply [Stoke's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes'_theorem), we obtain

$$\begin{align} \vec{k} \cdot \left[ \frac12 \int_S r^2 d\vec{a} - \frac14 \int_S \vec{r} (\vec{r}\cdot d\vec{a})\right]
= & \frac18 \int_S( 4r^2 \vec{k} - 2(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r})\vec{r}) \cdot d\vec{a}\\
= & \frac18 \int_S (\nabla \times ( r^2(\vec{k} \times \vec{r}))\cdot d\vec{a}\\
= & \frac18 \int_{\partial S} r^2(\vec{k} \times \vec{r})\cdot d\vec{r}
\end{align}
$$
When $S = \partial V$ is the boundary of some region $V$, the boundary of $S$ will be empty. This means the leftmost integral over $\partial S = \emptyset$ vanishes. As a result,
$$\vec{k} \cdot \left[ \frac12 \int_{\partial V} r^2 d\vec{a} - \frac14 \int_{\partial V} \vec{r} (\vec{r}\cdot d\vec{a})\right] = 0$$
Since this is true for all constant vector $\vec{k}$, what's inside the square bracket vanishes and

$$\frac12 \int_{\partial V} r^2 d\vec{a} = \frac14 \int_{\partial V} \vec{r} (\vec{r}\cdot d\vec{a})$$

Comment: Thank you very much for this nicely written proof! Your answer was in-depth and, as far as I can see, accurate and correct. I consider my question answered.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think you made a mistake: From line 3 to 4, you are summing $2r^2 \vec{k} + 3r^2 \vec{k}$ to be $4r^2 \vec{k}$ instead of $5r^2 \vec{k}$.

Comment: @Xeno, you are right, there is a typo. The $(\nabla \cdot \vec{k}) \vec{r}$ should really be $(\vec{k}\cdot \nabla)\vec{r}$ which generate an extra copy of $-r^2\vec{k}$. the final sum is still $4r^2\vec{k}$.

Answer (score 0):

The last identity is in fact correct, and it follows from the Divergence Theorem. So this leads me to believe that it will *not* hold for arbitrary surfaces, i.e., those that are not boundaries of a region. Indeed, that is so. Let's try the easiest example, the unit disk $D$ in the $xy$-plane. Then
$$\int_D \vec r(\vec r\cdot d\vec S) = \int_D \vec r (0) = \vec 0,$$
whereas
$$\int_D \|\vec r\|^2\,d\vec S = \left(2\pi\int_0^1 r^3\,dr\right)\vec k = \dfrac{\pi}2\vec k.$$