Can the gradient of a scalar field be expressed as a surface integral per unit volume?
I am familiar with the usual equation for the gradient of a scalar field $\varphi$
$$
\nabla \phi = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} \mathbf{i} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} \mathbf{j} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z} \mathbf{k}.
$$
In Butkov, 'Mathematical Physics', page 33, he has an equation for grad $\varphi$ in terms of the limit of a surface integral of $\varphi$ per unit volume.
$$
\nabla \phi = \lim_{\Delta V \to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta V} \iint \phi d\mathbf{S}.
$$
I do not understand this version. Is it even correct? If so, can someone explain how it agrees with the usual equation.
Edited: changed it to read 'surface integral'

Maybe this is more well-suited for math stackexchange, since the question only asks about the mathematical correctness of the formula, without referring to any physical interpretation.

We want to show that:
$$
\nabla \varphi = \lim_{\Delta V \to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta V} \int_S \varphi \, \textrm{d}\mathbf{S}
$$
Where $S$ is a surface of a closed volume. One can proof this formula by assuming that our volume is simply a cube $l^3=[-\textrm{d}a,\textrm{d}a]\times[-\textrm{d}a,\textrm{d}a]\times[-\textrm{d}a,\textrm{d}a] \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Then rewriting the integral we get:
$$
\int_S \varphi \, \textrm{d}\mathbf{S}=\mathbf{i}\left(\int_{l^2}\varphi(\textrm{d}a,y,z)\,\textrm{d}y\textrm{d}z\,-\int_{l^2}\varphi(-\textrm{d}a,y,z)\,\textrm{d}y\textrm{d}z\right)+
\mathbf{j}\left(\int_{l^2}\varphi(x,\textrm{da},z)\,\textrm{d}x\textrm{d}z\,-\int_{l^2}\varphi(x,-\textrm{da},z)\,\textrm{d}x\textrm{d}z\right)+
\mathbf{k}\left(\int_{l^2}\varphi(x,y,\textrm{da})\,\textrm{d}x\textrm{d}y\,-\int_{l^2}\varphi(x,y,-\textrm{da})\,\textrm{d}x\textrm{d}y\right)
$$
Minuses arise from the fact that surfaces are directed in the different direction at $\textrm{d}a$ and $-\textrm{d}a$.
Now $\Delta V=8\textrm{d}a^3$ and $\varphi$ can be extended in taylor series:
$$
\varphi(x,y,z) = \varphi(0,0,0) + (\partial_x \varphi) x+ (\partial_y \varphi) y+ (\partial_z \varphi) z + \mathcal{O}(\textrm{d}a^2)
$$
here after the derivative, $x=y=z=0$ I have used shorter notation. Now plugging it into our integral, simplifying and integrating one gets(in each direction $\varphi(0,0,0)$ cancels out and we are left with twice the derivative):
$$
\int_S \varphi \, \textrm{d}\mathbf{S}=\mathbf{i}\left((2 \textrm{d}a \partial_x \varphi) (4\textrm{d}a^2) \right)+
\mathbf{j}\left((2 \textrm{d}a \partial_y \varphi) (4\textrm{d}a^2) \right)+
\mathbf{k}\left((2 \textrm{d}a \partial_z \varphi) (4\textrm{d}a^2) \right) + \mathcal{O}(\textrm{d}a^4)
$$
Now $2 \textrm{d}a \partial_x \varphi$ is from the sum of two derivatives (minus cancels out with minus from taylor) and $4\textrm{d}a$ is a surface of a side of a cube. Simplifying we arrive with:
$$
\int_S \varphi \, \textrm{d}\mathbf{S}=8 \textrm{d}a^3\left(\mathbf{i}\partial_x \varphi+
\mathbf{j}\partial_y \varphi+
\mathbf{k}\partial_z \varphi\right) + \mathcal{O}(\textrm{d}a^4)
$$
dividing by $\Delta V=8\textrm{d}a^3$ and applying limit we get:
$$
\lim_{\Delta V \to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta V} \int_S \varphi \, \textrm{d}\mathbf{S} = \left(\mathbf{i}\partial_x \varphi+
\mathbf{j}\partial_y \varphi+
\mathbf{k}\partial_z \varphi\right)
$$
Which is exactly $\nabla \varphi$. To be precise our calculations were around (0,0,0) so we have calculated $\nabla \varphi(0,0,0)$ but you can place a test cube in any position and make a taylor around this new coordinates.
Using this definition you can also derive grad in cylindrical and spherical coordinates.


he has an equation for grad $\varphi$ in terms of the limit of a
volume integral of $\varphi$ per unit volume.

It is not a volume integral of $\varphi$, it is a surface integral of $\varphi$. You can gain some confidence that the equality is correct by choosing a reference frame where axis $x$ is directed along $\nabla\varphi$ in some point. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1958252/gauss-divergence-theorem-for-volume-integral-of-a-gradient-field
